# Databricks and Gitlab integration/automatization

Tags: gitlab, databricks, azure-databricks, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to create some ci/cd in gitlab. I would like to run update all databricks notebooks in Repos with the most current git code (some developers to not use dbx ui, but IDE such as VScode).

I was able to found azure devops integration, with running some

```html
stages:
  - update_dbx_notebooks

update_dbx_notebooks:
  stage: update_dbx_notebooks
  script: |
    -python -m pip install --upgrade databricks-cli
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  script:
    -echo "Checking out the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  branch"
    -databricks repos update --path "Repos/databricksUser/SL_dataprovider_staging" --branch "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

I have generated token, so I am able to pull/commit from databricks notebooks against gitlab fine. But I think gitlab runner must authenticate against databricks, right? Makes sense to create VM with gitlabrunner on Azure?

Does anyone have experience with gitlab/github integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create your gitlab-runner on Linux machine, add sudo privilegies   (or specific only for your pipeline) to `gitlab-runner` user
- Start runner, register it with your project
- Add to home config file with Runner profile `~/.databrickscfg`
  See [databricks cli docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html) (or you can use default, after manual settings)
- Ofcourse you have to verify your gitlab [repository against datbricks](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/gitlab-version-control.html).

Add pipeline to your `gitlab-ci.yml`

```html
stages:
  - update_dbx_notebooks

update_dbx_notebooks:
  stage: update_dbx_notebooks
  before_script:
    - echo "Installation of databricks-cli via $USER"
    - sudo python3 -m pip install databricks-cli
  script:
    - echo "Test ls dbx space"
    - databricks workspace ls /Users/username --profile Runner
    - echo "Checking out the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH  branch"
    - databricks repos update --path "/Repos/username/staging" --branch "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" --profile Runner
```

voila
[image]